# Advantage of single file deployment on .NET5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Single file deployment was available in .Net Core 3.0 and improves this mode in .NET 5. But, what's the advantage of Single file deployment? Do we really need it?

In ASP.NET MVC5, I can replace the static files directly, after I deploy the app.

In single file deployment mode, if I need temporarily replace the static file, I must deploy the app again.

Answer (score 2):

Single file applications are published and deployed as a single file. The app and its dependencies are all included within that file. When the app is run, the dependencies are loaded directly from that file into memory (In asp.net core 3.1, It packages binaries into a single file for deployment and then unpacks those files to a temporary directory to load and execute them). There is no performance penalty with this approach. When combined with assembly trimming and ahead-of-time compilation, single file apps are smaller and startup quickly.

More detail information, you could refer [Single file applications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-8/#single-file-applications) and [The design of single-file apps](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md).