# How can I put publish files in the custom folder in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, publishing, asp.net-core-6.0

When publishing, how can put dll files in a folder,  JSON files in a folder, or sometimes a bunch of files in a separate folder?

[image]

Move to

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to be able to categorize the files and that this is a request from the employer

Comment: Ok, I assume that you are publishing to IIS? How is the IIS supposed to know in what folder to look for the JSON files or the .NetCore files?

Comment: When Visual Studio can take over this task during publishing and give us a way to categorize the file in csproj, we won't have any problems in IIS. I am looking for a config in Visual Studio

Comment: I´m not seeing any benefits by doing this other then adding unnecessary complexity. What benefits are there by publishing into different folders?

Comment: To reduce the number of files, one could do: [Single-file deployment and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)? Or am I missing something when doing that?

Comment: @Luuk hmmm I´m not familiar with single file deployment. My concern regarding the question asked is if the files are organized into folders on publish, then how will the IIS know where to find what. Then there needs to be a config file for the IIS to know where to look for JSON or DLL´s..

Comment: @Luuk I found some good resource here regarding single file deployment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67379376/432074 Always fun to learn something new :)

Comment: The location where Microsoft should look can be found using: `dotnet --list-runtime`, but the (Microsoft) seems to follow the path to always include all those files when publishing.